# The whole or whole the

Tags: sentence-construction

> **whole the** chapter is full of printing errors which are the outcome of proof reader's carelessness.

Please tell the difference between **the whole and whole the**  as a whole and in the context of above example.

Comment: "**Whole the**" is simply incorrect English.

Comment: I concur. **whole the** is wrong. And as a rule of thumb, you should always specify the source of your examples.

Comment: "**Whole the**" is wrong and is probably being used as a pun or a joke. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be helpful to think of articles (*a/an* and *the*) as a special kind of adjective that always comes before any other adjective that modifies the same noun.

For example, "Look at the big blue dog" is correct, because *the* comes before the other adjectives. On the other hand, "I saw red a bird" is incorrect, because *a* comes after *red*, even though they both modify *bird*.

To use your example, "whole the chapter" is always wrong - *the* must come first. In contrast, "the whole chapter" is just fine, as it follows the rule.

For a more detailed overview of article usage, I encourage you to check out the [Purdue Online Writing Lab (OWL) page on it.](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)

Answer (score 1):

In the context

> **whole the** chapter is full of printing errors which are the outcome of
>   proof reader's carelessness.

"**whole the**" is probably being used as a pun or a clever little joke, because "**whole the**" is simply wrong. It's exactly the kind of mistake that you would expect from a printing error, like the one that the sentence you provided is describing. A native speaker would immediately see that the sentence should begin "**the whole** chapter is full of..."

In any other context, "**whole the**" is still wrong. It's simply gibberish and doesn't make sense. "**The whole**," on the other hand, is perfectly valid English and means exactly what you think it means (i.e., the entirety of something).